# View and save model value in one view at same time

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have one issue with ASP.NET MVC. I try to show and save same models same values in one view at same time.

In my view there are two sections. One side is purchase side and one side is sale side. And the model is same in both purchase and sale sides. Because in database sales and purchases saves in one table.

Now when i enter product name to one text box and press save button it writes both entered values in two text boxes.

Please  if you have solution this issue write your answers.

My view is like this.

```
@model PROJECT.TRANSACTIONS

  @using (Html.BeginForm("AddPurchase", "Transaction", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "addpurchase" }))
  *{*
              <div class="form-group div-style div-spec">
                        <div style="margin-top:2px;margin-left:18px;margin-right:0;float:left"> <label> Product : </label> </div>
                                <div style="margin-left:4px;float:left;">
                                 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PRODUCT, new { @class = "form-control editor-field", style = "max-width:280px;width:280px;float:left !important" })
                         </div>
                    </div>




             <div class="form-group div-style div-price">
                        <div style="float:left; padding-left:67%;margin-right:-20px ">
                            <input type="submit" style="padding:0 20px;margin-bottom:4px;margin-top:4px; margin-left:20px" value="Submit" name="purchase_submit" class="btn btn-default" />
                        </div>
             </div>     


  *}*


    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddSale", "Transaction", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "addsale" }))
  *{*

                   <div class="form-group div-style div-spec">
                        <div style="margin-top:2px;margin-left:18px;margin-right:0;float:left"> <label> Product : </label> </div>
                                <div style="margin-left:4px;float:left;">
                                 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PRODUCT, new { @class = "form-control editor-field", style = "max-width:280px;width:280px;float:left !important" })
                         </div>
                    </div>


            <div class="form-group div-style div-price">
                        <div style="float:left; padding-left:67%;margin-right:-20px ">
                            <input type="submit" style="padding:0 20px;margin-bottom:4px;margin-top:4px; margin-left:20px" value="Submit" name="sale_submit" class="btn btn-default" />
                        </div>
             </div>     

  *}*
```

And i have only one entity model.

```
   public partial class TRANSACTIONS
    {

     [StringLength(150)]
        public string PRODUCT { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Please show us your code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Code added to ticket please take a look on my code.

Comment: its because the two textboxes are the same, they have the same id, so it can't distinguish between the two. You can use javascript to achieve what you want to do anyway

Comment: Do you mean i need to save form values with ajax button or what ? Please could you give detailed information how to solve this issue with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I really need to see code, but it could be the textboxes name attribute is identical, which would cause this behavior if on the same form.  One way to handle is define a view model:

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
   public Entity Product { get; set;}

   public entity Sale { get; set; }
}
```

Second, change the model in the UI to SomeViewModel, and then render the name textbox on the product side to:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Product.Name);
```

And on the sale side:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Sale.Name);
```

The UI needs some level of distinction in order to map everything back to the server correctly.

Comment: thank you @Brian for your response. I added code to my question. Please could take a look at this code. May be there is another way to solve this issue.

Comment: If I click the submit button on the purchase form, it posts to AddPurchase, but won't post AddSale, so do you have logic in AddPurchase that saves to both? The same situation for AddSale.  The separate actions segregate the functionality, so I don't understand why you would have an issue saving to 2 places...

Comment: No they are different actions. One is AddPurchase and second is AddSale. I want to save purchase side fields when i press submit button in purchase side. Now i can save purchase side fields when i press submit button but it automatically update fields in sale side also. because the values of both side is same. I want solution for this issue.